# Any Possible Use QR Code as an AR (augmented reality) Marker?

Tags: qr-code, augmented-reality

Is there any possible use QR Code (Quick Response Code) as an AR marker?

What I need is recognize QR Code content first (This could be done by zxing lib).

Then use QR Code position mark and alignment mark to launch AR.

If possible, where should I start or what documents can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what you're after is a [fiducial marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker). For computer vision projects, they're similar to QR codes but usually designed to be simpler and faster to detect.

They look like this:

[image: Fiducial Marker Examples]

There are a few open source libraries around that provide functionality for fiducial markers:

- [Chilitags](https://github.com/chili-epfl/chilitags) (C++, requires OpenCV, LGPL)
- [ARToolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/) (C/Java, includes rendering support, GPL)
- [reacTIVision](http://reactivision.sourceforge.net/) (Standalone app, mainly designed for multitouch tables, GPL)

Chilitags looks very promising, but ARToolkit is great if you want to get up and running fast. I only included reacTIVision because of the awesome amoeba-shaped markers they use